# validate vs validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

There is a `validate` specifier that can be directly used on the association (see 4.1.2.12 at this [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and also a `validates_associated` (see 3.2 at that [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated)).
Where do both differ?

Comment: Here is an [updated link to the Rails Guide entry on validates_associated](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated)

Answer (score 2):

They both validate the associated model(s).

The difference is that the first is an option on the association (e.g. `belongs_to`, `has_many`, etc). E.g. you define the 'act of validation' in your association.

In a classic "Author has many Books" example, say you enable `belongs_to :author, :validate => true` on the Book model. Every time you validate a Book model, the associated Author must also be valid.

The other is a separate validates rule you can add to your other validations. So, in this case you enable the validation of an associated object together with other validation rules.

This can work the other way around. In Author: `has_many :books ; validates_associated :books`. When you validate the Author object, all books are validated as well.

Comment: To use validates_associated without double-validating, you'd have to explicitly turn off :validate on the association. I'm still wondering why validates_associated exists if it does the same thing as the default. Any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same question as @zardox but I'm not sure this really answers it. Could you explain what the actual difference is between the two methods other than the position at which they're declared. Are you suggesting that in the first instance, the book actually creates a validation backpressure up to author and forces the author to be invalid if the book is invalid? This doesn't seem very encapsulated.

Comment: I'm still confused, too. What's the difference between has_many :books, :validate => true and has_many :books ; validates_associated :books ?? (Your description of the difference makes them sound like they are the same, which is the opposite of explaining how they are different.)

Comment: Tyler, it appears that the primary differences on the has_many between using the :validate option or using the separate validates_associated method is that :validate allows you to disable validations on a has_many association (according to the docuemenation it's true by default on has_many) while validates_associated has a variety of options (:unless, :if, :on (context)) that are not available to the inline :validate option.

Comment: Thinking about this question too. Here is described difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395506/when-to-use-validates-associated-v-belongs-to-parent-validate-true but i didn't check yet this.

Comment: `validates_associated :children` will also append errors like this: `self.errors.add(:children, :invalid) unless children.all? { |child| !child.marked_for_destruction && child.valid?` (where `self` is the `parent`). This can be useful when designing a public API

Comment: See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/associated.rb#L8 for the source code of Rails related to my comment above