# When to use "validates_associated" v "validate => true"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It seems that in rails you can define association validations in two places, either on the association itself:

```
class Child

  belongs_to :parent, :validate => true

end
```

Or as a validation callback:

```
class Child

  belongs_to :parent

  validates_associated :parent

end
```

What is the difference between these two methods?

**Testing the difference**

I thought that maybe the former creates a backpressure and enforces that the parent is only valid if the child is valid:

i.e. (when setting :validate => true)

```
child.valid? # => false
child.parent.valid? # => also evaluates to false because of the :validate => true condition


# do whatever it takes to make the child valid again
#...
child.valid? # => true
child.parent.valid? # => true
```

However I tested it and this doesn't happen. So what's the difference (if any) between the two methods?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had to dig into the Rails (3.0.7) code to find some differences.  The core functionality looks the same to me -- they both seem to call `valid?` on the associated record(s).

The key differences that I did find only appear when using the `:autosave` feature or when either destroying the associated object or marking it for destruction.  For example, I have:

```
class AbsentDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :autosave => true, :validate => true
end
```

And I see the following behaviour:

```
user = User.new(:username => "Jimmy")
user.valid?                               # => true
ad = AbsentDate.new(:user => user)
user.username = nil                          
user.valid?                               # => false
ad.valid?                                 # => false
ad.errors.full_messages                   # => ["User username cannot be empty"]
ad.user.mark_for_destruction
ad.valid?                                 # => true
```

Note that marking the user for destruction resulted in a valid AbsentDate.  Also note that there is only one error message.  Now consider this case:

```
class AbsentDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :autosave => true
  validates_associated :user
end
```

This is what I see happening:

```
user = User.new(:username => "Jimmy")
user.valid?                                # => true
ad = AbsentDate.new(:user => user)
user.username = nil
user.valid?                                # => false
ad.valid?                                  # => false
ad.errors.full_messages                    # => ["User username cannot be empty", "User is invalid"]
ad.user.mark_for_destruction
ad.valid?                                  # => false
```

Two error messages this time, and the AbsentDate is still false even though its user has been marked for destruction.  I was able to replicate these results by calling destroy instead of mark_for_destruction.

One last thing: if you use `validates_associated`, you get several options (`:if`, `:unless`, `:on`, `:message`) that you won't have if you use the flag on `belongs_to`.

Comment: Great answer. I haven't been through the code in a console yet but really appreciate you pulling this out - thank you

Comment: Additional information: `validates_associated :children` in the `Parent` model will `errors.add(:children, :invalid) unless children.all?(&:valid?)` (actually will test a little more stuff like `marked_for_destruction?`, see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/associated.rb#L8). This can be useful when you want to have errors on `parent.errors[:children]` (when designing an API for example)