# rails f.submit checking another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand that in form_for, I'm able to validate that form's table in my model, but what if I wanted to validate the "f.submit"ted data against another table?

Specifically, a Staff can only checkout a Radio in the Checkout model/table if both the Staff and Radio exists in their own respective tables.

How would I go about passing in the Staff and Radio table into my Checkout validation criteria?

Thanks!

Comment: Table: database table?  HTML table on the page?

Comment: db table, html already checks for equality

Answer (score 0):

Forms in Rails are not actually linked to validation (not in same way as say Symfony2) they simply display error messages.

You can nest resources in forms with [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) this is used together with [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

```
<%= form_for(@member) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field(:name) %>    
  <%= fields_for :avatar, @member.avatar do |avatar_fields| %>
    <%= avatar_fields.text :url %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar
end
```

You can create a validation for a model association with `validates_associated` or by passing `validates: true` when declaring an association. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395506/when-to-use-validates-associated-v-belongs-to-parent-validate-true) for details.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar, validate: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar
  # or
  # validates_associated :avatar
end
```

Comment: ah, text is actually text_field, but what's the :url < that's being used here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to use a presence validation on the associations (assuming there are associations between these models). For example if your checkout model has radio_id and staff_id columns then you might have

```
belongs_to :radio
belongs_to :staff
validates :radio, presence: true
validates :staff, presence: true
```

If that isn't enough you can write custom validation methods with the `validate` method

class Checkout < ActiveRecord::Base
      validate :something_custom

```
  def something_custom
    # call errors.add to mark the object as invalid 
  end
```

end

You can also wrap this up in a validator module if you end up reusing this frequently.

Comment: i didn't (don't know how to) set up an association with the models. also, the "validates :radio" only refers to that particular model's column, no?

Comment: The validation i suggested would check that the associated radio exists in the database. Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for more information about associations - can't make any recommendations as I don't know what it is you are trying to model